# Evaluator class import are not getting in ignite-ml dependency?

Tags: java, maven, ignite

I have added the Ignite-ml dependency in my maven project and then tried to access some classes, such as in the example:

> https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/ml/tutorial/Step_1_Read_and_Learn.java

However the package `org.apache.ignite.ml.selection.scoring.evaluaton` is not present in Ignite-ml dependency.

Used Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-ml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There are several classes which are not present in jar which is downloaded by maven dependency. (KMeansTrainer,DenseVector,etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Evaluator` class was added recently under the following ticket: [IGNITE-8669](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8669). It hasn't been released yet. It will be included into Ignite 2.7

If you need it right now, you can use a nightly build: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#nightly-builds

**UPD:**

Also you used version 2.6 in your `pom.xml`, but actually it should be 2.6.0

Comment: there are some classes which is not getting like KMeansTrainer and DenseVector, this classes are already  documented on apache ignite site

Comment: Still the same issue after changes in version 2.6 to 2.6.0

Comment: Do you look for them in the right package? `KMeansTrainer` is in the following package: `org.apache.ignite.ml.clustering.kmeans`. Make sure, that your IDE imported your changes in the pom file. If the issue persists, then let me look at your project.

Comment: Yes and I have also checked class files in that jar but the packages is missing

Comment: You can download file jar file from the following page: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-ml/2.6.0 It contains the needed package, I checked